# Debian 11 installed but need to connect to Internet

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, network-interface, iwlwifi

I got Debian 11 installed on my laptop as Standard System Utils. I've been having issues with the network card that I have when installing so I couldn't connect to my network in the installation but got the firmware for my network card after installation and it's running (hopefully) correctly when I check `lspci` which gives `01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev29)` as well as checking `systemctl status networking` which gives `Loaded: loaded (lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active(exited)` in the block of code.

Checking the `/etc/network/interfaces` only gives me the loopback network interface as well as in `ip a`.

I want to connect to my network but I can't figure it out. I've checked on guides and such but most of the commands for those packages I don't have. I tried installing NetworkManager from my usb but gave me an error saying that `dpkg: error: unknown option -n` after entering `dpkg -install /mnt/network-manager_1.30.0-2_amd64.deb`. Anyone know how I can connect to my network?

Comment: long options use TWO dashes, while short options use ONE. `dpgk -i package` OR `dpkg --install package`! With `dpkg -install` it assumes that both `-i` and `-n`, as well as `-s` `-t` `-a` `-l` (twice) are all selected as option flags, but most, like `-n` do not exist for `dpkg`. Thus the error message.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Use `dpkg -i` (single dash) or `dpkg --install` (two dashes).

`dpkg -install` does nothing you want, because of a quirk in the difference between short and long options.

With a single dash, most unix commands will assume that every subsequent letter is a separate option, and a subsequent argument applies to the option denoted by the last letter.

So `dpkg -install` would be equivalent to `dpkg -i -n -s -t -a -l -l`, and (*thankfully*) more than half of those are not actual recognized flags so `dpkg` quit with an error message rather than blithely do what the separate flags might have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

for the wifi hardware mentioned, you also need some extra packages:

```
firmware-iwlwifi
intel-microcode
firmware-misc-nonfree
```

from non-free section.

To find if you have non-free section enabled in /etc/apt/sources.*, and packages are available, try:

```
$ apt-cache policy firmware-iwlwifi
firmware-iwlwifi:
  Installed: 20210315-3
  Candidate: 20210315-3
  Version table:
 *** 20210315-3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

you may have to may be download those packages' deb files on USB drive and copy to your system. then run

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```